# Use StreamBuilder as root of navigation stack with GoRouter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, navigation

Currently I have a StreamBuilder switching between a `HomePage` and `LandingPage` depending on the current auth state. The issue I have encountered is that I cannot pop the stack to the original `/landing` directory on a state change. This means that when a user logs in, the `AuthPage` remains on the top of the stack and the StreamBuilder builds the `HomePage` underneath.

AuthGate

```dart
class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData ? const HomePage() : const LandingPage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

LandingPage
This pushes the AuthPage to the stack.

```dart
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingPage({super.key});

  ...

        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: UniqueKey(),
              onPressed: () {
                context.push('/auth');
              },
              label: const Text('Get started'),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: UniqueKey(),
              onPressed: () {
                context.push('/auth');
              },
              label: const Text('Log in'),
            ),
          ],
        )

  ...

  }
}
```

[Stack before auth change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3tLa.png)

[Stack after auth change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5sd4.png)

Note how the `AuthPage` remains on the top of the stack but the Widget under `StreamBuilder` changes to the `HomePage`

<sub>(This is my first Stack question so please feel free to ask me to amend any information etc.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GoRouter, then what you want to achieve should be done through GoRouter similarly to this:

```dart
GoRouter(
        refreshListenable:
            GoRouterRefreshListenable(FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()),
        initialLocation: '/auth',
        routes: <GoRoute>[
          GoRoute(
            path: '/landing',
            name: 'landing',
            builder: (context, state) {
              return LandingPage()
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                path: 'auth',
                name: 'auth',
                builder: (context, state) => const AuthPage(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
          ),
        ],
        errorBuilder: (context, state) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Text('404'),
          );
        },
        redirect: (context, state) async {
          final userRepo = injector.get<UserRepository>();

          final user = FirebaseAuth.instance;

          const authPaths = [
            '/landing',
            '/landing/auth',
          ];

          bool isAuthPage = authPaths.contains(state.subloc);

          if(user != null) {
            if (isAuthPage) {
              return '/home';
            }
          }
          if(!isAuthPage) {
            return '/auth';
          }
          return null;

          
        },
      );

class GoRouterRefreshListenable extends ChangeNotifier {
  GoRouterRefreshListenable(Stream stream) {
    notifyListeners();
    _subscription = stream.asBroadcastStream().listen(
      (_) {
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }

  late final StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Please also read documentation on of GoRouter.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't too sure about GoRouter's role in this. I will RTFM next time.